# Sales Discount Journal Entry

Tags: accounting, discount

I have this problem that I have found difficult to solve. First am not a professional accountant so it might be a bit obvious to accountants bear with me. I will explain the question with an example

Let say John Company Ltd sales cleanliness service to its customers, on credit. The CEO decided to give discount for all its Customers for the services it offered on Sept. The Invoice to customer X is generated and looks like this sheet:

[image: Invoice In Spreadsheet]

Now an accountant needs to post to the General Ledger all the transactions to the affected accounts. As Far as I know, without Sales discount I would just credit sales with 423.73, credit tax with 76.27, then debit AR with 500 (I used [this generator](https://www.calculatestuff.com/business/sales-tax-calculator) to get the numbers).

Now my question is, with Discount added, what will be the T-accounts in the general ledger?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to follow and I am not able to understand what it is you are trying to ask.  Please proofread and edit the question to make it clearer.  Thanks!

Comment: let me try rephrasing. Sorry for being confusing

Comment: Check if the question is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under IFRS 15, "The transaction price is the amount to which an entity **expects** to be entitled in exchange for the transfer of goods and services."

The discount of $50 does not appear anywhere as a T-Account.

Sometimes a merchant advertises that a product is "worth" $10,000 and provides a $9,950 discount. It does not mean that $9,950 should appear in the ledgers. It is incorrect to enter the $9,950 as Revenue, and incorrect to enter $9,950 as Discount Expense.

Comment: Thank you. Can you expand a little bit with where Sales Discount comes into play?